# How to trust a certificate in Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate, signed, pfx, trusted

I am using `Windows 7`, and want to run signed scripts from `Powershell`, the `security-settings` of Powershell are set to `"all-signed"`, and my scripts are signed with a `valid certificate` from my company. I have also added the `.pfx-file` to my local certificate store `(right-clicked the pfx-file and installed)`.

However, when I start a signed script, I get a message that says:

```
"Do you want to run software from this untrusted publisher?
File Z:\Powershell Signed Scripts\signed.ps1 is published by CN=[MyCompanyName] and is not trusted on your system. Only run scripts from
 trusted publishers.
[V] Never run  [D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [A] Always run  [?] Help
(default is "D"):"
```

Since I want to automatically call these scripts on my systems, I would like to add my imported certificate to the trusted list on my system, so that I do not get a message anymore when I run a signed script for the first time. How can I make my certificate a trusted one?

Comment: Are you sure that the public certificate of the certification authority that emit your développement certificate exists in your certificate repository ?

Answer (score 11):

> How to trust a certificate in Windows Powershell

Indeed, you can do this without any mmc :)

First, check the location of your personal certificate named for example "Power" :

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse cert:\CurrentUser\ |where {$_ -Match "Power"} | Select PSParentPath,Subject,Issuer,HasPrivateKey |ft -AutoSize
```

(This one should be empty:)

```
gci cert:\CurrentUser\TrustedPublisher
```

Build the command with the path to your certificate:

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem    Certificate::CurrentUser\My\ABLALAH
```

Next work on [certificate store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.open%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (*Here I work on two certificate store : user & computer*)

```
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store "TrustedPublisher","LocalMachine"
$store.Open("ReadWrite")
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()
```

Check, you should find your certificate :

```
ls cert:\CurrentUser\TrustedPublisher
```

Comment: In your example to store the certificate, you are using `"TrustedPublisher","LocalMachine"` which is only accessible with Administrator priviliges. In the next lines you are referring to `CurrentUser\TrustedPublisher` which is accessible by users. Thus I would suggest to change `"LocalMachine"` to `"CurrentUser"` so that it becomes a full working example.

Comment: That ls command!!! Yes!!! So glad you showed that in your answer.  Super helpful. 

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to verify that the script is signed properly and that you have the correct certificate installed in the correct certificate store.

Use the [`Get-AuthenticodeSignature`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347607.aspx) cmdlet to get information about the signed script.

Also review [Scott's guide](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx) for signing certificates.

Comment: The certificate should be specifically put in the Trusted Publishers container