# .Net Core Docker WebApi RemoteCertificateChainError - Connecting 2 Docker Containers (UI + API)

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I have 2 .NET core projects that work perfectly with each other when I run the normal, I have an API and an MVC UI. When I run them in docker containers, I go on my API with swagger, I figured out how to connect my PostgreSQL and insert data successfully. When I go on my UI and I call the API I get this error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors.
I created a certificate and have it in my .NET project. I am guessing I have to do something different to make this work with a container. (If this is what is wrong, I’m not sure yet.)
To put it in my normal project I did this.

```
.UseKestrel(serverOptions =>
                {
                    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5010);
                    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5011, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        listenOptions.UseHttps("localpfx.pfx", "password");
                    });
                });
```

I have a Dockerfile in my .NET core project. I am not using docker-compose.
Any ideas on how to get my UI to call my API both running in separate containers? This is the last part of my project.
Thank you.

P.S.

```
MVC UI project =   "httpPort": 5010,        "sslPort":  5011
API project =      "httpPort": 5000,        "sslPort": 5001
```

Edit:
Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
#USER ContainerAdministrator
#RUN net localgroup administrators /add "User Manager\ContainerUser"
#USER ContainerUser
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5011
#EXPOSE 5010
EXPOSE 80
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
#ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://*:5011

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["UserUISolution.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./UserUISolution.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "UserUISolution.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "UserUISolution.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "UserUISolution.dll"]
```

Comment: Please share you dockerfile's

Comment: Are you using self signed certificate? If so, did you make it trusted on your machine? I think in this case it would work ok on your machine but not on container, because container doesn't trust the certificate by default

Comment: Yes I created a self signed cert, It is trusted as well. The lock icon in browser says Valid for certificate. When I run project in kestrel everything works great. When I run on container they both work alone but when UI calls API I get the Error.
Separately I can use Swagger on API.

Comment: So last night I took off all the HTTPS on my containers. My containers worked perfectly than! My UI talked to my API no issues. So now I'm 100% sure this is a HTTPS certificate issue. I'm assuming I need to get my cert in my Docker Containers then it may work.

Comment: How do you call API from UI? Directly via js or UI calls API from controller using `HttpClient`?

Comment: Opt #2.  using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
            {
               using (var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/account/getusers"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the error occurs because you are using self-signed certificate and it is not trusted. You need to make the `UI` container to trust the certificate used for `API`. You can either make the container [to trust a certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815145/how-to-trust-a-certificate-in-windows-powershell) or trust it programatically. For the second option it's needed to configure `HttpClient` to trust the specific certificate.

For `ASP.NET Core` it's preferred to use [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Configuration in **UI project** will be the following

```
//this validator will trust incoming certificate with matching thumbprint
public class SingleCertificateValidator
{
    private readonly X509Certificate2 _trustedCertificate;

    public SingleCertificateValidator(X509Certificate2 trustedCertificate)
    {
        _trustedCertificate = trustedCertificate;
    }

    public bool Validate(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2, X509Chain x509Chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            return true;

        string thumbprint = x509Certificate2.GetCertHashString();
        //todo: add more validation logic if needed
        return thumbprint == _trustedCertificate.Thumbprint;
    }
}
```

In `Startup.cs`

```
services
    .AddHttpClient("Default")
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2("localpfx.pfx", "password");
        var certificateValidator = new SingleCertificateValidator(certificate);

        return new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = certificateValidator.Validate
        };
    });
```

Usage

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public TestController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestHttpClient()
    {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Default");
        var response = await client.GetAsync("url");

        //...
        return Json(result);
    }
}
```

For "manually" instantiated `HttpClient` (`new HttpClient`)

```
//...
var certificateValidator = new SingleCertificateValidator(certificate);
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = certificateValidator.Validate
};
var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
//...
```